# Symfony 2.7 EntityType -> QueryBuilder between StartDateTime and EndDateTime or null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

How can I select only the stores that are available?
My entity has a startDateTime and an endDateTime. Both fields has nullable=true.

If startDateTime is null then it must not be considered.
The same is for the endDateTime.

It try this, but it selects only the stores with this start and enddate:

```
$builder->add(
    'firstStoreChoice',
        EntityType::class,
        [
            'class'        => 'MyBundle\Entity\Store',
            'property'     => 'name',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'attr'         => ['data-init' => 'select2', 'data-select2-width' => '100%'],
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.startDateTime is null')
                        ->orWhere('s.startDateTime > :now')
                        ->andWhere('s.endDateTime is null')
                        ->orWhere('s.endDateTime < :now')
                        ->setParameters(['now' => new \DateTime()]);
                },
            ]
        );
```

Store 1:
Start: 2017-05-19 09:17:02
End: 2017-05-19 09:17:02

Store 2:
Start: 2017-02-01 13:53:00
End: 2017-02-02 13:53:00

These stores aren't available because the enddate is in the past.
Today is 2017-05-30 09:39:00.

Can somebody push me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to nest your conditions:

```
$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('s');

return $qb
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->lt('s.StartDateTime', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'),
            $qb->expr()->isNull('s.StartDateTime')
        )
    )
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->gt('s.EndDateTime', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'),
            $qb->expr()->isNull('s.EndDateTime')
        )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this sadly does not work. I got no results....
although I have stores with null values in EndDateTime and a StartDateTime < now.

Comment: ok. it was my fault. it works now - I had mistaken the lt and gt ... of course the startdate must < than now, and the enddate has to be > than now. Please update your answer.. than I will accept.

Comment: Yes, it was in my first post version :) Updated.